# Spring MVC Bind Nested Classes

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a requirement wherein i need to save the values of 3 entities from UI to database. As hierarchy shown below

```
Company->Employees
Company->Users
```

Company being the parent entity which has two child tables Employees and Users

Now I need to design a single screen to accept all the three table fields from it, I can have all the fields in one PO and then before saving i can directly map to each entity while saving to DB.

But I wanted to have a separate classes for each entity Like

```
public class Company{
   private String companyName;
   private String companyAddress;
   .....
   private Employee employee;
   private User user;
}
```

Now my question is how do I map the **employee** and **user** attributes in UI and get the values directly on submit from jsp/html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

Using thymeleaf i was able to bind the object as shown below

```
th:field="*{company.employee.name}"
```

and also initializing the child object whenever the parent object is initialized.